# How to stop stacking on high load websocket app

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

Wrote an app for collecting transactions from equities of NYSE and sending it through websocket. I am using gorilla websocket and what I have:

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

func (tm *TicksModel) websocketConnection() {
    go tm.writeMessages()

    http.HandleFunc("/", tm.echo)
    log.Println("http server started on :", 8126)
    err := http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8126", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("8126 ERROR ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}

func (tm *TicksModel) echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, Collectingchan chan string) {
    var (
        message     []byte
        ticker      string
        sendMessage string
        err         error
        v           *websocket.Conn
        i           int
        whichS      int
        tickerObj   *tickerModel
        ok          bool
    )

    tm.upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }
    c, err := tm.upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }

    defer c.Close()

    for {
        message, err = nil, nil
        _, message, err = c.ReadMessage()
        log.Println(">>", string(message))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("ERROR", err)
            tm.removeConnection(c)
            return
        }
        if string(message) == "Client" {
            log.Println("NEW CLIENT", c.RemoteAddr())
        }

        if message[0] == 'a' {
            ticker = string(message)[1:]

            tm.mx.Lock()
            if tickerObj, ok = tm.Tickers[ticker]; ok {
                if len(tickerObj.WSclients) == 0 {
                    Collectingchan  <- message
                }
                tickerObj.WSclients = append(tickerObj.WSclients, c)

                log.Println("TICK LISTENERS ADD", ticker, tickerObj)
            } else {
                tickerObj = &tickerModel{}
                Collectingchan <- message
                tickerObj.WSclients = append(tickerObj.WSclients, c)
                tm.Tickers[ticker] = tickerObj

                log.Println("TICK LISTENERS ADD", ticker, tickerObj)
            }
            tm.mx.Unlock()

        } else if message[0] == 'r' {
            ticker = string(message)[1:]

            tm.mx.Lock()
            if tickerObj, ok = tm.Tickers[ticker]; ok {
                for i, v = range tickerObj.WSclients {
                    if v == c {
                        tickerObj.WSclients = append(tickerObj.WSclients[:i], tickerObj.WSclients[i+1:]...)
                        if len(tickerObj.WSclients) == 0 {
                            sendMessage = "r" + ticker + "\n"
                            Collectingchan <- message
                        }
                        log.Println("TICK LISTENERS REMOVE", ticker, tickerObj)
                    }
                }
            }
            tm.mx.Unlock()
        }
    }

}

func (tm *TicksModel) writeMessages() {
    var (
        toWSMessage wsSendModel
        tickerObj   *tickerModel
        wsocket     *websocket.Conn
        err         error
        ok          bool
    )

    for {
        toWSMessage = <-tm.WSocketChan
        if tickerObj, ok = tm.Tickers[toWSMessage.Ticker]; ok {
            for _, wsocket = range tickerObj.WSclients {
                err = wsocket.WriteJSON(toWSMessage)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println("write error ticks", wsocket.RemoteAddr(), ":", err)
                    tm.removeConnection(wsocket)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func (tm *TicksModel) removeConnection(c *websocket.Conn) {
    var (
        wsocket     *websocket.Conn
        i           int
        sendMessage string
    )

    tm.mx.Lock()
    for ticker, tickerObj := range tm.Tickers {
        for i, wsocket = range tickerObj.WSclients {
            if wsocket == c {
                tickerObj.WSclients = append(tickerObj.WSclients[:i], tickerObj.WSclients[i+1:]...)
                if len(tickerObj.WSclients) == 0 {
                    tm.socketChanObject.getChan(tickerObj.SocketNumber, true) <- "r" + ticker
                }
                log.Println("REMOVE CONNECTION FROM TICK", ticker, tickerObj)
            }
        }
    }
    tm.mx.Unlock()
}
```

The map looks like this:

```
type TicksModel struct {
    Tickers          map[string]*tickerModel
    upgrader         websocket.Upgrader
    socketChanObject socketModel
    WSocketChan      chan wsSendModel
    mx               sync.Mutex
}

type tickerModel struct {
    WSclients    []*websocket.Conn
    SocketNumber int
}
```

After some time, new connections connects than disconnects after a minute. Application doesn't send new data, it stacks. What do you think?

Comment: It looks like there's a data race on `tm.Tickers`.   Run the application with the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector) and fix the reported problems.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, it should be fixed with mutex?

Comment: One possible fix is to use a mutex.  Another problem with the program is that a single slow or stuck client can block the entire server.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I have added the race flag and found out that problem is on the map. But I am curious, how to solve if the problem in the slow client?

Comment: The Gorilla chat example shows how to protect against slow clients.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thank you. And thank you for race advice. Now it is working